# react-router isn't re-rendering redux connect()ed components on route change

Tags: react-redux, react-router-redux

I'm using [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) for navigation and have nested `connect()`ed components. This seems to work fine, except that my nested components don't re-render when the react-router route changes.

Specificallyl, in the structure below, `App` and `Sidebar` are `connect()`ed components and they both require information from `state`. When I click a `Link` in `Sidebar`:

- a `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE` action is firing,
- I have react-router-redux's `routerReducer` being combined into my state so the state is updating,
- App re-renders and the new route is shown,
- but Sidebar doesn't re-render so the "active" `Link` isn't updated the `activeClass` is never changed.

What could be going wrong here?

*Router*

```
<Router component={App}>
   <Route path="foo" component={Foo}/>
   <Route path="bar" component={Bar}/>
   <Route path="baz" component={Baz}/>
</Router>
```

*App*

```
<div> 
  <Sidebar/>
  <div>
    {children}
  </div>
</div>
```

Sidebar

```
<nav>
   <Link to="/foo" activeClass="active">Foo</Link>
   <Link to="/bar" activeClass="active">Bar</Link>
   <Link to="/baz" activeClass="active">Baz</Link>
</nav>
```

Comment: I'm getting around this problem by passing the current time arbitrarily into Sidebar (`<Sidebar time={Date.now()}/>`). The fact that it's different each time seems to force a re-render, but doesn't really fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue (not using Redux), and it seems to be React deciding not to call render again for your sidebar even though App re-renders. I fixed it by wrapping the Sidebar in [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) which will cause Sidebar to re-render whenever your route changes.

Something like this:

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'
// or 'react-router-dom' on v4.x
class Sidebar extends Component {...}
export default withRouter(Sidebar)
```

Answer (score -1):

this problem is well documented at react-router's guides page https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md#dealing-with-update-blocking

TL;DR make sure your components are location-aware. either by using sCU or HoC

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)